# Interpolate NAs in matrix (bilinear)

Tags: r

very basic problem but I still can't find a solution:

I have a matrix / data.frame with (surface-temperature) measurments containing NAs.

`matrix(c(3,4,NA,NA,5,5,6,7,6,NA,NA,NA),ncol = 3,byrow = T)`

So I have NAs within the "surface" and at the outside.

```
> matrix(c(3,4,NA,NA,5,5,6,7,6,NA,NA,NA),ncol = 3,byrow = T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4   NA
[2,]   NA    5    5
[3,]    6    7    6
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
```

I need to inter- / extra-polate the missing values, e.g. with bilinear interpolation.

Thanks for your help,
Matthias

Comment: Check [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/akima/versions/0.6-2.1/topics/bilinear)

Comment: Thanks, but the bilinear() and the bilinear.grid() functions of the akima package don't accept NAs in the z-input.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a matrix, you can fill in the blanks row-wise using any appropriate type of regression. For each row you set up a regression where the x variable is the column number and the y variable is the the cell's value. After that, you can fill in the blanks just by using `predict` on a vector of the column numbers. You then do the same thing column-wise.

This leaves you with two matrices, each with most of the `NA` values filled in. You then take the mean result for each cell (dropping `NA` values where they still exist). This will give you interpolated values for each cell (unless you have entire rows *and* entire columns which are `NA`, in which case the `NA` at the intersection remains (note that you can fix these by running the algorithm twice)

Which regression method you use is dependent on the underlying data. For a 3 x 3 grid, an `lm` is fine:

```r
mat <- matrix(c(3,4,NA,NA,5,5,6,7,6,NA,NA,NA),ncol = 3,byrow = T)

rowwise <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
  if(sum(!is.na(x)) < 2) rep(NA, length(x))
  else predict(lm(x ~ seq_along(x)), newdata = list(x = seq_along(x)))
}))

colwise <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) {
  if(sum(!is.na(x)) < 2) rep(NA, length(x))
  else predict(lm(x ~ seq_along(x)), newdata = list(x = seq_along(x)))
})

colwise[is.na(colwise)] <- rowwise[is.na(colwise)]
rowwise[is.na(rowwise)] <- colwise[is.na(rowwise)]

mat_fixed <- mat
mat_fixed[is.na(mat)] <- ((colwise + rowwise)/2)[is.na(mat)]

mat
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    3    4   NA
#> [2,]   NA    5    5
#> [3,]    6    7    6
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA

mat_fixed
#>      [,1]     [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 3.00 4.000000  4.5
#> [2,] 4.75 5.000000  5.0
#> [3,] 6.00 7.000000  6.0
#> [4,] 7.50 8.333333  7.0
```

You will notice that the original values from `mat` are unchanged and we have done a pretty good job of interpolating the missing values. I prefer to get a visual impression of the interpolation, so we can compare the original matrix:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(reshape2::melt(t(mat)), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

To the interpolated one:

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(t(mat_fixed)), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

This looks pretty good to me.

Depending on the size of your matrix and so on, it may be better to try an interpolating function such as `approx`, or use `loess` also works well, though these won't extrapolate, so they not guaranteed to fill all the missing values at the edges of your matrix. If I had a very large (image-sized) matrix, I might use `approx` first for interpolation then `lm` for the extrapolation, but for a 3 x 3 matrix, `lm` on its own is fine.

A more complete implementation for interpolation would be something like:

```r
interpolate <- function(y) 
{
  complete_cases <- is.finite(y)
  if(sum(complete_cases) == 0) return(rep(NA, length(y)))
  if(sum(complete_cases) == 1) return(rep(y[complete_cases], length(y)))
  approx(seq_along(y), y, seq_along(y))$y
}
```

And for extrapolation:

```r
extrapolate_left <- function(y)
{
  x <- seq_along(y)
  ssOK <- which(!is.na(y))[1:2]
  ssNA <- which(is.na(y))
  ssNA <- ssNA[ssNA < ssOK[1]]
  
  y[ssNA] <- predict(lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x, y)[ssOK,]), list(x = x[ssNA]))
  round(y, 6)
}

extrapolate_right <- function(y)
{
  x <- seq_along(y)
  ssOK <- tail(which(!is.na(y)), 2)
  ssNA <- which(is.na(y))
  ssNA <- ssNA[ssNA > ssOK[2]]
  
  y[ssNA] <- predict(lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x, y)[ssOK,]), list(x = x[ssNA]))
  round(y, 6)
}
```

Which you could use to fill vectors:

```r
fill_vector <- function(y) {
  y <- interpolate(y)
  x <- seq_along(y)
  if(all(is.na(y))) return(y)
  if(is.na(y[1])) y <- extrapolate_left(y)
  if(is.na(tail(y, 1))) y <- extrapolate_right(y)
  y
}
```

and matrices:

```
fill_matrix <- function(mat) {
  rowwise <- t(apply(mat, 1, fill_vector))
  colwise <- apply(mat, 2, fill_vector)
  colwise[is.na(colwise)] <- rowwise[is.na(colwise)]
  rowwise[is.na(rowwise)] <- colwise[is.na(rowwise)]
  mat[is.na(mat)] <- ((colwise + rowwise)/2)[is.na(mat)]
  mat
}
```

You can see that this works pretty well if we take a 50 * 50 matrix and fill half of it with `NA` values:

```r
x <- seq(0, pi, length.out = 50)
m <- outer(sin(x), sin(x))
m[sample(length(m), 1250)] <- NA
```

Plot it with the `NA` values:

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(t(m)), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

And plot it with the values "filled" in using our `fill_matrix` method:

```
ggplot(reshape2::melt(t(fill_matrix(m))), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks!
Works fine!
I thought I just missed a very obvious function but you just programmed the fuction!

Answer (score 1):

Not as robust for extrapolation as Allan's solution, but it's simple and fast:

```
library(zoo)

m <- matrix(c(3,4,NA,NA,5,5,6,7,6,NA,NA,NA),ncol = 3,byrow = T)
rowMeans(simplify2array(list(na.approx(m, rule = 2), t(na.approx(t(m), rule = 2)))), TRUE, 2)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 3.00    4  4.5
#> [2,] 4.75    5  5.0
#> [3,] 6.00    7  6.0
#> [4,] 6.00    7  6.0
```